# Send data to fragment after is initialized

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have problem when I send data to initialized tab. In method `getData()` I received adapter is null and recyclerview is also null.

```
TabOne one = new TabOne()
one.getData(populatedList)
```

The error is next =>

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void OneAdapter.setData(java.util.List)' on a null object reference.
```

Is maybe better idea to send data through bundle in fragment or maybe any other idea.

I called `getData()` becuse here is response from API.

```
public class TabOne extends Fragment {

        private Unbinder unbinder;

        @BindView(R.id.fab)
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

        @BindView(R.id.recycler_view_recycler)
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        private OneAdapter oneAdapter;

        private List<Response> response = new ArrayList<>();

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one, container, false);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            oneAdapter = new OneAdapter(getContext(), response);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(oneAdapter);

            return view;
        }

        public void getData(List<Response> response){
            oneAdapter.setData(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            unbinder.unbind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use bundle for communication.

Comment: bundle is preferred way but again depends on use cases

Comment: where are you call one.getData(populatedList) ?? if you call it from another activity or fragment you doing it wrongly

Comment: Yes I call this from another fragment @Radesh. What is best way for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call method of fragment from an other Activity/Fragment.

You have several way for solve this problem

**plan A** (suggested)

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

**1** : Create `EventClass.java` like this

```
public class EventClass{

    private List<FILL IT WITH YOUR OBJECT> populatedList;

    public EventClass(int populatedList) {
        this.populatedList= populatedList;
    }

    public int getPopulatedList() {
        return populatedList;
    }
}
```

**2** : Use it

in your activity instead of this

```
TabOne one = new TabOne()
one.getData(populatedList)
```

Use EventBus and post your event like this

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new EventClass(populatedList));
```

**3** Grap your data inside fragment. Add this function to your Fragment

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(EventClass event) {
     oneAdapter.setData(event.getPopulatedList());
}
```

**4** don't forget to register and unregister your EventBus in Fragmet

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);//add in onCreateView
//...
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);//add in onDestroyView
```

**plan B**

Use **interface design** for callback in fragment. You must create an interface for change data like `changingDataListener` and `implements` that in your **Fragment** and call the callBack from **Activity**

**plan C** (Advanced)

Use **RxJava** with `PublishSubject` you can create Observable for observes new data and whe new data arrives you can update your adapter.

**BELIEVE ME** plan A is mush more simple!

Comment: Thanks what you think about viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener() ? This will work ?

Comment: @Mirko i don't think so. one single single work is using static populatedList that i don't suggest but it works